# Error when installing pyminizip on OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to install pyminizip using OS X El Capitan and I am getting the following error:

> Failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/l9/n4qbh8w554qcqlq88wkvn1ph0000gn/T/pip-install-bc9ds31c/pyminizip

Comment: Please try to lay your question out in a manner that people can read.

Comment: I made some changes. Essentially deleted all the superfluous information.

Comment: How are you trying to install it?